# Reshape tensorflow placeholder based on some condition

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to reshape a placeholder according to a condition described below:

```
input=tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [3,4])
equate_labels = tf.equal(tf.expand_dims(input, 0), tf.expand_dims(input, 1))

sess=tf.Session()
result=sess.run(equate_labels, feed_dict={input:[[1,0,1,1], [1,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0]]})
print(result)
sess.close()
```

Actual Output:

```
[[[ True  True  True  True]
  [ True  True False  True]
  [ True  True False False]]

 [[ True  True False  True]
  [ True  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True False]]

 [[ True  True False False]
  [ True  True  True False]
  [ True  True  True  True]]]
```

Desired Output:

```
[[[ True ]
  [ True ]
  [ False]]

 [[ True ]
  [ True ]
  [ True ]]

 [[ False]
  [ True ]
  [ True ]]]
```

above output is based on below pseudo algorithm:

```
if in each row_of(Actual Output) number_of(True)>=3 then assign True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following.

```
out = tf.expand_dims(
    tf.math.greater_equal(
        tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(equate_labels, tf.int32), axis=2), 3), axis=-1)
```